# Checking a single bit in SCTLR_EL1 Register on Cortex-A72 Armv8 running Linux

Tags: c, arm, armv8

i have been trying to check the UCI bit (UCI, bit [26]) in SCTLR_EL1 Register on a Corte-A72 ARMv8 RUnning linux.
So i wrote a simple kernel module :

```c
#include <linux/module.h>
#include<linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

static inline void write_SCTLR_EL1(uint64_t val){
    asm volatile("msr s3_0_c1_c0_0 , %0" : : "r" (val));
    asm volatile("isb" : : : "memory");
}

static inline uint64_t read_SCTLR_EL1(void){
    uint64_t val;
    asm volatile("mrs %0, s3_0_c1_c0_0" : "=r" (val));
    return val;
}

int __init enable_cache_instructions(void){
    uint64_t value = read_SCTLR_EL1();
    printk(KERN_INFO "VALUE IS <0x%016llx> from SCTLR_EL1.", value);
    return 0;
}

void disable_cache(void) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "Instructions disabled \n");
}

module_init(enable_cache_instructions);
module_exit(disable_cache);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

and the value of the Register is : 0x0000000034d5d83d (binary format = 110100110101011101100000111101).
So i wrote a simple c code to check UCI bit value :

```c
int main (){
    unsigned long register_value = 886429757; // decimal format of the Register value
    register_value |= 1ULL << 26; //trying to set UCI bit to 1 if it is disabled
    printf("After set : %lu\n",register_value);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output : 886429757**

Is that right ? The value of UCI bit is 1 ?
i mean, if the value is not set, the start and the end values should be different.

i tried checking the value in c code as well :

```c
register_value  &=  (1ULL << 26);
printf("After check : %lu\n",register_value);
```

but the output is : 67108864.

Thank You.

Comment: first off stick to hex if you are doing binary stuff, not decimal.  If you want to isolate a bit then use and not or.  look at the truth tables, in this context you use or to set a bit high and use and to set bits (you dont care about) low).  so and with 1<<26.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's ok hex format. i am using OR and not AND bitwise operation because i'm trying to set the value of the bit and with AND operation, for example, if the bit is disabled i can not set it (of course in c code i can not modify the real value of the bit, i'm just trying to get to know if the bit is enable or not using the value of the register before i can modify it).

Comment: if you want to see if it is set then use and if you want to set it then use or.  significantly easier to see that you changed it by using hex

Comment: you are on the right track if that is the real question here.  orring with 1<<(bit number)

Comment: I guess I misread trying to set with trying to see, re-reading you are trying to set so you are doing it correctly, yes.

Comment: I have not read up on that register in a while, if it is not working it may not be a simple case of read-modify-write a register, but perhaps there are permissions and modes, etc, that are required to change a feature.

Comment: I have root privileges on machine and i'm using a kernel module so i think it should not be a problem checking, reading and writing the value. About my code, i have read the value with kernel module, then i need to know if the UCI bit is enable or not. my strategy (i'm not sure that is a good way ) based on reading the value of the entire register first,using read function in kernel module, and then using OR bitwise operation and finally checking again the register value (in hex format following your advice). if UCI bit is set, the start value and the final value should be the same, right ?

Comment: So, that should be a check too. is that true ?

Comment: if it were, decimal too would work, but if its not the same or if you want to see what the value of the bit is hex is easier, you can simply look at it, decimal you need to feed it through a calculator to binary, octal, or hex so you can then easily see the bit value.

Comment: if it is set then in and out will be the same yes, any base printout.  But if you are trying to debug your code, that is when hex helps and that is when you can also mask the bit and print it to see if it is set without having to even look through the hex values.  the printf would either be 0x00000000 or 0x04000000

Comment: okok, i got it. i printed AND (register_value  &=  (1ULL << 26) and the output in hex is 4000000.